# How do I execute a query that returns true or false if a row exists?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net

I'm familiar with creating queries like this in my code:

```
var word = dbcon.Query<Word>("SELECT Correct FROM Phrase WHERE Id = ?", id).FirstOrDefault();
```

But is there a way I could execute this query and have it return just a true or a false if the value existed or not?

```
"SELECT Correct FROM Phrase WHERE Id = ?"
```

Note that I am using SQLite.net so I would be interested in solutions that use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `Any()` extension method, so like:

`var word = dbcon.Query<Word>("SELECT Correct FROM Phrase WHERE Id = ?", id).Any();`